# Customize the look of the Silverlight Control Toolkit drag / drop

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, silverlight-toolkit

Is there a way to override the template of or restyle the carrot (and even completely remove as I need in one case)? The carrot being the position marker where the drop will occur. I'd also like the ability to change the icons used during dragging - I've seen an infinity symbol, an arrow, and a strike-through circle, for which all I'd like to use custom icons. Unfortunately, I'm also confused as to when a given icon displays itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reviewing the docs it would appear that the `DragDropTarget` has a `GetInsertionIndicatorGeometry` which I suspect is responsible for the various symbols shown when dragging.

Hence for you to replace these symbols you will need to inherit the specific target type you are using and override this protected member to inject your own geometries.

Comment: Ah, yes, that looks promising. I can even use the implementation as an example: http://bit.ly/agff89 (sorry, couldn't find it in the original Codeplex source). I guess I'll just root around until I can find how the icon assets are loaded too; hopefully this is virtualized as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did this work for you? I tried to create my own geometry to display some other element while dragging rather the actual elements from the TreeView .. it doesn't work ..